# i want to make a code for comments and replay system

Tags: laravel, comments

this is a post.php model

```
public function comments()
{

    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class); //aquivalente a App\Comment
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

 Public function addComment($body) //nombre de la variable post Task $task el segundo es la variable o los datos a que se va a pasasr
{     

    $user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
    $this->comments()->create(compact(['body', 'user_id']));

}

Public function addreply($body)
{
  dd($body);
 $this->comments()->create(compact(['body', 'parent_id']));

}
```

this is commentController

```
class CommentsController extends Controller
{
public function store(Post $post)
{


    $this->validate(request(), [
        'body'=> 'required|min:5'
            ]);

   $post->addComment(request('body'));

    return back();
}
```

}
and this is for migration table

```
{
    Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('parent_id')->default(0);
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('body');
        $table->timestamps();


    });
    Schema::table('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{  
    Schema::dropForeign('post_id');
    Schema::dropForeign('user_id');
    Schema::dropIfExists('comments');

}
```

so the problem is here when i send a comment or add comment it show user_id not default. first i added like a default but it has problems

so can someone help with it? 
i want to make like send a message and other user can respond a message 
i think i have to add some code but i do?

Comment: i suggest you add `parent_id` to `comments` table for insert `id` parent comment and add another relation in `CommentsController` that point to himself.

Comment: okey, im trying to do the replay, now i can send a comment .                $user_id = \Auth::user()->id;   
        i added this code. and foreign key now i have to make it replay able

Comment: with `parent_id` filed make comment reply able.just add parent comment id in this filed for answer comment and 0 for new comment

Comment: okey, but i think i have to add in model the relationship like many right?

Comment: yes. add method like this in your comment model : `public function children()
{

    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class,'parent_id'); 
}`

Comment: i have add like that but i cant migrate because it says undefined method foreign key

Comment: this is inner key.parent_id pointed to id in same comment table.

Comment: i have to create a new table body or text for responde to the comment or how do i do? because i really dont understand well i was looking for another   pages but they dont explain well.

Comment: @viass add comment model file and i send complete answer.

Comment: i have add a comment model ready, and now my code is working, then when i read the code how to display? 'i want to order by time like youtube ' are u there?

Comment: For sort post comments with time use `$post->comment->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')`

Comment: okey thanks  for your help